# Improve a jarring Facebook authentication process on Android?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

The app's launcher activity is called LoginActivity (not to be confused with the Facebook SDK Activity of the same name). This contains a button "Sign into Facebook" which fires the startFacebookLogin() method shown below. The result works, in that the app gets access to the Facebook user account. But the process for the user is very ugly and involves a whole bunch of screens flashing up in front of them. This is what happens:

1. LoginActivity starts, showing the Sign In button and the user taps the button - startFacebookLogin() gets called
2. The Facebook SDK's LoginActivity starts
3. The Facebook authentication UI displays briefly but usually immediately closes if previously authenticated
4. The app's LoginActivity (not Facebook's) is visible again
5. MainActivity starts

In essence after tapping the Sign In button the entire screen is redrawn four times and it looks particularly bad as the Facebook auth screen is white, but all of the app's activity are dark in colour. It's quite a visual assault. Some of these screens may be necessary, certainly number 5 is, but...

Where the Facebook SDK is going to sign the user straight in as they are already authenticated with this app, why is it showing any UI at all? Is there any way to fix this, or is it just a flaw with the Facebook SDK we have to live with?

Even where the user needs to sign in, is there anything that can be done to limit the jarring nature of 2 and 3 above? Can I check if the user is authenticated without the Facebook SDK opening any UI?

```
private void startFacebookLogin() {
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
        // callback when session changes state
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            saveUserNameAndStartMainActivity(user.getId());
                        }
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void saveUserNameAndStartMainActivity(String userId) {
    ((EmbarApplication)getApplication()).saveUserId(userId); // saves to shared prefs
    openMainActivity(); // starts the main activity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you grab the active session

```
Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
if (s.isOpened()) {
  // user is authenticated, skip all login stuff
}
```

You should be able to tell the user is authenticated without any ui popping.